# MS Access to sql server searching

Tags: c#, sql-server

How to use this code if we are going to use sql server database becaUSE in this code we used MS Access as the database

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
  String pcode = txtPcode.Text;
  int ctr = productsDS1.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
  int x;
  bool found = false;

  for (x = 0; x<ctr; x++) {
    if (productsDS1.Tables[0].Rows[x][0].ToString() == pcode) {
      found = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (found == true) {
    txtPcode.Text = productsDS1.Tables[0].Rows[x][0].ToString();
    txtDesc.Text = productsDS1.Tables[0].Rows[x][1].ToString();
    txtPrice.Text = productsDS1.Tables[0].Rows[x][2].ToString();
  } else {
    MessageBox.Show("Record Not Found");
  }

  private void btnNew_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
    int cnt = productsDS1.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
    string lastrec = productsDS1.Tables[0].Rows[cnt][0].ToString();
    int newpcode = int.Parse(lastrec) + 1;

    txtPcode.Text = newpcode.ToString();
    txtDesc.Clear();
    txtPrice.Clear();
    txtDesc.Focus();
```

> > > here's the connectionstring

Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Registry Path=;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;Data Source="J:\2009-2010\1st sem\VC#\Sample\WindowsApplication_Products\PointOfSales.mdb"

Comment: Suggestions: Add the parts of the code that are missing and format it.  Show how you currently connect to Access.  Tell us what you have tried.

Comment: I don't see where you use Access in this code.

Comment: Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Registry Path=;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;Data Source="J:\2009-2010\1st sem\VC#\Sample\WindowsApplication_Products\PointOfSales.mdb"

Comment: to access sql server, change your connection string: http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Answer (score 1):

It would be total abuse of a SQL Server to implement code like this against a server. My C# is a bit rusty, but it looks like this code walks through every row in `productsDS1`, comparing the "Pcode", "Desc" and "Price" to those entered into the text box.

The proper way to implement this is via either a stored procedure on the SQL Server that is passed those three values and returns either a recordset of matching record(s) (or possibly a RecordID to be used in a separate retreival process) OR at least to form a SQL statement to retreive the data (i.e. `"SELECT * FROM productsDS1 where Pcode = '" & txtPcode.Text & "' AND Desc = '" & txtDesc.Text & "' AND Price = " & txtPrice.Text`). I would recommend the first method since the second is susceptible to SQL injection.

(This methodology would also have been more appropriate against the Access db.)

Comment: @data jockey: I have formatted your answer to make it more readable - hope you don't mind :)

Comment: +1 However, you don't need to use stored procedures to protect yourself against SQL injection. Parameterized queries/prepared statements should solve the problem just fine.